# Linux zip command generates archive file with two successful numeric passwords

Tags: linux, zip

I used this command to successfully password protect a zip file on Linux :

```
zip -P 9000 hash.zip hash.py
```

I wrote a program to test every possible password on it from 1 to 100000. The problem is that the program found two successful passwords:

- the first is `9000`
- the second is `79095`

Is there any security vulnerability in Linux zip command?

Comment: The short answer is that many possible keys can unzip a file because of the way its encryption works. Also, ZIP passwords are generally insecure. See http://math.ucr.edu/~mike/zipattacks.pdf (Especially the part about Eli Biham's attack)

Comment: if you want to encrypt a particular text file either use a plain vimcrypt which is also breakable (depends on a crypt setting e.g. set cm=blowfish should be fine i think) or http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#encrypt-simple. hope it will give you some ideas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Password 79095 unzip the file but create unusable file and you cannot use it.

Answer (score 0):

Original ZIP encryption is insecure. You should use InfoZIP's/WinZIP's AES encryption.

Comment: When file is decrypted, first decrypted small header, and one or two bytes which are checked against the pre-calculated value - to check if password is valid. If they match, then password is considered valid. And since it is just two bytes, there is a chance that incorrect password will be accepted.